# How to install php-redis extension using the official PHP Docker image approach?

Tags: php, redis, docker, dockerfile

I want to build my PHP-FPM image with `php-redis` extension based on the [official PHP Docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/php/), for example, using this Dockerfile: [php:5.6-fpm](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/a413eb0123d10321928696ffea7442bed7dc0dc7/5.6/fpm/Dockerfile).

The docs say that I can install extensions this way, installing dependencies for extensions manually:

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm
# Install modules (iconv, mcrypt and gd extensions)
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install iconv mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Without Docker, I installed it with `apt-get install php5-redis`. But how can I install it using the approach above?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Redis is not an extension that is included in “php-src”, therefore you cannot use `docker-php-ext-install`. Use [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/):

```
RUN pecl install --onlyreqdep --force redis \
&& rm -rf /tmp/pear \
&& docker-php-ext-enable redis
```

On alpine php 7.3.5 we can use:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache pcre-dev $PHPIZE_DEPS \
&& pecl install redis \
&& docker-php-ext-enable redis.so
```

Comment: TimWolla, thanks, I'll try it. So, I need to install `pecl` as well before all of these?

Comment: TimWolla, pecl isn't included by default.

Comment: What if I want to use a different image for Redis?

Comment: @IlGala This command installs *php extension for redis not redis server itself*

Comment: What do the -o and -f options do?

Comment: @LarsNyström -o --onlyreqdeps: install all required dependencies, -f  --force: will overwrite newer installed packages

Comment: Previously I made the mistake of using `docker-php-ext-enable redis` without first doing `pecl install redis`. As a result, phpinfo made it appear that redis was installed, because all of the .ini configuration was there, but the redis module itself was not. Thank you for you help!

Comment: The last one worked fine for me on alpine 3.16 with PHP 8.0.

Comment: "unrecognized option --onlyreqdep", seems there are no such option anymore in PECL comming with "wordpress:6.3-php8.2-apache"

Answer (score 76):

My opinion, the easiest way is:

`RUN pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis`

;)

Comment: Yes, it is a modern way answer.

Comment: Does NOT work. Specifically docker-php-ext-enable redis does NOT install any configuration files anywhere. It simply does nothing.

Comment: Gives me error docker-php-ext-enable -- not found. Can you help here ?

Comment: I saw the comment by @SzczepanHołyszewski and just did the first command (`RUN pecl install redis`), not both (`RUN pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis`). That's all that was needed for me!

Answer (score 21):

I've found two ways to install [php-redis](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis) extension for official [php-fpm Docker image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/php/). Here they are:

**The first way is to compile redis from sources and install.**

```
RUN curl -L -o /tmp/redis.tar.gz https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/2.2.7.tar.gz \
    && tar xfz /tmp/redis.tar.gz \
    && rm -r /tmp/redis.tar.gz \
    && mv phpredis-2.2.7 /usr/src/php/ext/redis \
    && docker-php-ext-install redis
```

`docker-php-ext-install` script is included in php-fpm image and can compile extensions and install them.

**The second way you can do it is with PECL.**

As TimWolla [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31369892/202550), you can do it with [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/), but in my case, PECL isn't installed by default.

```
RUN pecl install -o -f redis \
&&  rm -rf /tmp/pear \
&&  echo "extension=redis.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/redis.ini
```

Comment: I had to add a `mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext` before the `mv`.

Comment: I used pecl but had to add RUN apk add --no-cache autoconf git g++ make from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44191638/4018940

Answer (score 21):

Slightly revised version of [starikovs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31623759/3448044) and [skyred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32197845/3448044) answers for the current PHP 7 version of the docker image (tested on `php:7.0.8-fpm-alpine` and `php:7.0.8-alpine`).

Uses the newly released `3.0` version (June 2016) for PHP 7.

```
ENV PHPREDIS_VERSION 3.0.0

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext/redis \
    && curl -L https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/$PHPREDIS_VERSION.tar.gz | tar xvz -C /usr/src/php/ext/redis --strip 1 \
    && echo 'redis' >> /usr/src/php-available-exts \
    && docker-php-ext-install redis
```

Comment: I tried out the answer from @starikovs and I was never able to effectively enable the extension. This answer worked the first time!

Answer (score 11):

Based on @starikovs answer. I added a variable for docker style.

```
# install phpredis extension
ENV PHPREDIS_VERSION 2.2.7

RUN curl -L -o /tmp/redis.tar.gz https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/$PHPREDIS_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && tar xfz /tmp/redis.tar.gz \
    && rm -r /tmp/redis.tar.gz \
    && mv phpredis-$PHPREDIS_VERSION /usr/src/php/ext/redis \
    && docker-php-ext-install redis
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use redis as session handler;

```
RUN { \
    echo 'session.save_handler = redis'; \
    echo 'session.save_path = tcp://redis:6379'; \
} >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-redis.ini
```

If you want to use redis extension with PHP 7 in 2015 (borrowed from [skyred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32197845/531320)'s answer);

```
ENV PHPREDIS_VERSION php7

RUN curl -L -o /tmp/redis.tar.gz https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/$PHPREDIS_VERSION.tar.gz \
    && tar xfz /tmp/redis.tar.gz \
    && rm -r /tmp/redis.tar.gz \
    && mv phpredis-$PHPREDIS_VERSION /usr/src/php/ext/redis \
    && docker-php-ext-install redis
```

Answer (score 7):

Tried few ways. On alpine php 7.3.5 we can use:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache pcre-dev $PHPIZE_DEPS \
        && pecl install redis \
        && docker-php-ext-enable redis.so
```

Comment: Where is the variable $PHPIZE_DEPS set and what should be in it?

Comment: $PHPIZE_DEPTS set by docker alpine. and it use for build pecl extension like Redis
https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php

Answer (score 6):

This works for alpine images:

```
RUN set -xe \
    && apk add --no-cache --update --virtual .phpize-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    && pecl install -o -f redis  \
    && echo "extension=redis.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/redis.ini \
    && rm -rf /usr/share/php \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* \
    && apk del  .phpize-deps
```

Edit: Added missing backslash

Answer (score 3):

I'm using combination of PECL and PHP official docker extension script

```
RUN pecl bundle -d /usr/src/php/ext redis \
&& rm /usr/src/php/ext/redis-*.tgz \
&& docker-php-ext-install redis
```

For PHP7 you need to wait for official redis pecl release or use git:

```
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install git -y -q \
&& git clone -b php7 https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis.git /usr/src/php/ext/redis \
&& docker-php-ext-install redis
```

Comment: Redis PECL extension v3 is available for PHP 7 since 2016-06-10.

Answer (score 1):

This is a docker solution, use this code in `Dockerfile`.

```
COPY --from=mlocati/php-extension-installer /usr/bin/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/
RUN install-php-extensions redis
```

Image sources: https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer

Comment: A little more detail on this (e.g. a link to the appropriate github repo) would be good

Answer (score 0):

Slightly revised version of [starikovs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31623759/3448044) and [skyred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32197845/3448044) answers for current version of the docker image.
Tested on php:5-fpm-alpine

```
# install phpredis extension
ENV PHPREDIS_VERSION 2.2.8

ADD https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/$PHPREDIS_VERSION.tar.gz /tmp/redis.tar.gz
RUN tar xzf /tmp/redis.tar.gz -C /tmp \
    && mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext \
    && mv /tmp/phpredis-$PHPREDIS_VERSION /usr/src/php/ext/redis \
    && echo 'redis' >> /usr/src/php-available-exts \
    && docker-php-ext-install redis \
    && rm -rf /usr/src/php/ext/redis
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile you can clone the repo and install it with:

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis.git /tmp/phpredis \
&& cd /tmp/phpredis \
&& git checkout -b 3.1.2 \ ## or the release you need #
&& phpize \
&& ./configure \
&& make \
&& make install
```

Answer (score 0):

For image php:7.2-fpm-alpine.

```
RUN apk add autoconf gcc g++ make && pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis
```

You may need to update before

```
apk --update upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `RUN apk add --no-cache php83-pecl-redis` for me.