# How to see other container from one container in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have compose file as follows;

```
redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
    - "6379:6379"
 php:
    build: .
    image: php:fpm
    volumes:
    - ./code:/var/www/html
    links:
      - redis:redis
    networks:
    - code-network
```

I'm entering into php container with the following command.

```
docker exec -it php_id /bin/bash
```

but I can't run "redis-cli" command in this container. What do I need to do to run it.

I added "links" parameter to compose file but it didn't.

Comment: could you remove the `networks` part from the compose file, attach to the php-container, run `apt update -yq && apt install -yq iputils-ping` and try `ping redis`?

Comment: I didn't understand what you said.So when I enter into php container I want to run redis-cli, so I don't want to come out and enter into redis container again.

Comment: could you post the output of `docker-compose --version`, please? and is that really your entire compose file? Also, the contents of your `Dockerfile` would be helpful.

Comment: docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880fe

Comment: Did you add some args for redis_cli when you execute it? Such as specifying redis server?

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the php-fpm container in a network of its own. Here is a fixed compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  php:
    build: .
    image: php:fpm
    volumes:
      - ./code:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - code-network
      - default

networks:
  code-network:
```

See [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for more info on compose networking.

About the redis-cli issue: You'd need to add the appropriate repository on the php-fpm container and then install it. As you are using the php:fpm image, you propably want to use redis with some php-application, therefore you don't need debians `redis-cli` package, but rather the php-extension.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369867/how-to-install-php-redis-extension-using-the-official-php-docker-image-approach) post for more info.